# Prove that a set is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

> Prove that a set is a subset of another, using predicates and (if needed)
>   quantifiers:

(A $\cap$ C) $\cup$ (B $\cap$ D) $\subseteq$ (A $\cup$ B) $\cap$(C $\cup$ D)

Should I start with the whole statement, and rewrite it using predicates and logic until a tautology comes out **or** am I supposed to somehow come from the left side of the $\subseteq$ to the right side?

I tried the first option and only ended up going in circles and the second one I’m not sure how it’s supposed to look like.

Thanks!

Comment: No, do *not* start with the statement to be proved and derive a tautology.  That is considered very sloppy mathematics.  It can also lead to errors if your steps aren't reversible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in (A \cap C) \cup ( B \cap D)$. Then $x \in A \cap C$ or $x \in B \cap D$.

Suppose $x \in A \cap C$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. Therefore $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in C \cup D$, i.e. $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$.

Suppose $x \in B \cap D$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in D$. Therefore $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in C \cup D$, i.e. $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$.

It follows that $(A \cap C) \cup ( B \cap D) \subseteq(A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$.

Comment: So I can understand the explanation, after drawings a Venn diagram for it. So basicaly as a predicate it would look like: x $\in$  A and x $\in$ C $\rightarrow$ $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$  . But how could I say using logic that the statment is true.

Comment: Using logic you can see the answer from @Siddharth Bhat. However, I think that solve your problem using the definition of union and intersection is the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

You can write the predicate for the left hand side and the right hand side, then attempt to show one implies the other. The answers are in a spoiler tag so you can try them out yourself :)

- find some predicate $P$ which models $x \in (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap D)$

  > $P \equiv (x \in A \land x \in C) \lor (x \in B \land x \in D)$
- Now find a predicate $Q$ for $x \in (A \cup B)\cap (C \cap D)$

  > $P \equiv (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in C \lor x \in D)$
- For subsets relations $L \subseteq R$, the predicate is: $\forall x \in L \implies x \in R$.   That is, prove that $P \implies Q$.

To show that $P \implies Q$:

> the rule that will come in handy is the distributivity of $(\lor)$ over $(\land)$: $(a \land b) \lor (c \land d) = (a \lor c) \land (b \lor d)$.

Comment: I don’t see how the 2 are equivalent: $(a \land b) \lor (c \land d) = (a \lor c) \land (b \lor d)$ , after trying to come from one side to other I just go in circles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of a subset.

> $B$ is a subset of $A$ if for all $x\in B$, $x\in A.$

Now let $x\in (A\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)$. Then either $x\in (A\cap C)$ or $x\in (B\cap D)$

Case I: $x\in (A\cap C)$

Then $x\in A$ and $x\in C$. Thus $x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\in (C\cup D)$. Thus $x\in (A\cup B) \cap (C\cup D)$.

Case II: $x\in (B\cap D)$

Then $x\in B$ and $x\in D$. Thus $x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\in (C\cup D)$. Thus $x\in (A\cup B) \cap (C\cup D)$.

So in either case $x\in (A\cup B) \cap (C\cup D)$. Therefore $(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap D) \subseteq (A\cup B) \cap (C\cup D)$

Answer (score 0):

Below an almost completed proof

[image]

Comment: It would be better to write out the proof using MathJax instead of including a picture. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.